# Problem with local variable while defining a function

Tags: variables, jupyter-notebook, local

I'm having a problem with the following line of code, in particular I don't get why  I'm obtaining the error "local variable 'TnuoT' referenced before assignment" when I've defined TnuoT only inside the gstar function.
Thanks for your help!

```
me =0.51e-3
def gstar(x,i):
    if(x>me): TnuoT = 1.
    else: 
        if(i==1): Tnuot = pow(4./11,4/3)
        elif (i==2): Tnuot = 4./11
    return TnuoT

gstar(me-1,1)
```

Comment: Is it a typo?
`Tnuot` vs `TnuoT`

Comment: I'm an idiot, been looking for a solution for a day. Thanks my friend